# I need to change just the strings that contains " " in a string

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to change a string of a property. I just need to change the ones that have an space on it.

Bad Url:
"url.com dummy/"

Good Url:
"url.com/dummy/"

Actual:

```
   {  
     test: "test1",  
     Attach: [{  
        Type: "img",  
        Url: "https://url.com dummy/"
     },
     {  
        Type: "img",
        Url: "https://url.com/dummy/"
     },
     {  
        Type: "img",
        Url: "https://url.com dummy/"
     },
     {  
        Type: "img",
        Url: "https://url.com/dummy/"
     }] 
   }
```

Expected:

```
   {  
     test: "test1",  
     Attach: [{  
        Type: "img",  
        Url: "https://url.com/dummy/"
     },
     {  
        Type: "img",
        Url: "https://url.com/dummy/"
     },
     {  
        Type: "img",
        Url: "https://url.com/dummy/"
     },
     {  
        Type: "img",
        Url: "https://url.com/dummy/"
     }] 
   }
```

As you can see, the properties that I need to change are inside of an array.

I need to have a script to verify in the whole collection.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$regex` in an aggregation pipeline to find the documents with space. Then use `$replaceAll` to replace space with slash. Finally `$merge` back the result to the original collection.

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/T3o9uWPJaM-) for your reference.